# Eclipse shows validation error with jQuery 1.11.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jquery-validate

I am using jquery-1.11.1.min.js in my Eclipse project and it's showing me a validation error.

The error message is:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

It shows the error at this line:

```
"undefined"!=typeof window?window:this
```

It doesn't give me any issues in the web application, everything works fine. It's just annoying to look in Eclipse. I have tried disabling validation on js files and even tried suspending all validations for the project. Doesn't help.

Any clues?

Note: The error is on the jquery-1.11.1.min.js file itself that I downloaded from the jQuery site. It's not in my custom script.

Comment: Use `"undefined" !== typeof window?window:this`

Comment: Am I missing something or am I right that there isn't an assignment at all in the code snippet shown?  Is that the whole line triggering the error?

Comment: This is part of the code that shows the error, not the complete line. I have added one additional note to my question.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the code around this snippet?

Comment: The complete jqeury file is from here - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js